# Linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, sobolev-spaces

For $a<b \in \mathbb{R}$, let $G=(a,b)$ be a bounded interval. For every $x \in G$, let the generalized function $\delta_x$ be defined by $$ \int_G \delta_x \phi(x)dx = \phi(x) ~~ \text{for every} ~~ \phi \in C^0(\overline{G}) $$
How can I show that for every $x \in G$ and every $p \in [1, \infty]$ the function $\delta_x$ is a linear continuous functional on $W^{1,p}(G)$, that is $\delta_x \in W^{1,p}(G)\text{*}$ for $x \in G$ and every $p \in [1,\infty]$ where $\text{*}$ denotes the dual space.

Comment: For $f\in C^1(a,b)$ define $\delta_xf := f(x)$ ($x$ is fixed here). Now show that $|\delta_xf|\le C\|f\|_{W^{1,p}}$ for some $C > 0$ and all $f\in C^1(a,b)$. If now $C^1(a,b)$ is dense in $W^{1,p}(a,b)$ (which I guess, but don't know for sure), the functional can be uniquely extended to a functional in $W^{1,p}(a,b)^*$.

Comment: Thanks! How would I show that $\lvert \delta_x f \rvert \leq C \lVert f \rVert_{W{1,p}}$?

Comment: For $p=1$: Choose some $\xi\in (a,b)$ such that $\int_a^b|f(t)|\,dt = (b-a)|f(\xi)|$. Then you have$$|f(x)|\le|f(x)-f(\xi)| + |f(\xi)| = \left|\int_\xi^xf'(t)\,dt\right| + \frac1 {b-a}\int_a^b|f(t)|\,dt.$$This should help.

Comment: That should surely be of help, but damn I am not yet really able to see it..

Comment: The right hand side is not larger than$$\int_{\min\{\xi,x\}}^{\max\{\xi,x\}}|f'(t)|\,dt + \frac 1 {b-a}\int_a^b|f(t)|\,dt\le\max\left\{1,\frac 1 {b-a}\right\}\left(\int_a^b|f'|\,dt + \int_a^b |f|\,dt\right) = C\|f\|_{W^{1,1}},$$where $C$ is the max.

Comment: Of course that's it, I did not think of using max, thank you!

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Btw if you make/copy your comments (or just the first one) into an answer I will accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer for the case $p=1$. Let $f\in C^1[a,b]$. First, we choose some $\xi\in (a,b)$ such that $\int_a^b|f(t)|\,dt = (b-a)|f(\xi)|$. Then we have (for all $x\in (a,b)$)
\begin{align*}
|f(x)|&
\le |f(x) - f(\xi)| + |f(\xi)| = \left|\int_\xi^x f'(t)\,dt\right| + \frac 1 {b-a}\int_a^b|f(t)|\,dt\\
&\le \int_{\min\{\xi,x\}}^{\max\{\xi,x\}} |f'(t)|\,dt + \frac 1 {b-a}\int_a^b|f(t)|\,dt\le\max\left\{1,\frac 1 {b-a}\right\}\|f\|_{W^{1,1}}.
\end{align*}
Due to this inequality, the linear functional $\delta_x : C^1[a,b]\to\mathbb K$ (where $\mathbb K$ is either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$), defined by $\delta_x(f) := f(x)$, is continuous w.r.t. the $W^{1,1}$-norm. And as $C^1[a,b]$ is dense in $W^{1,1}(a,b)$, it can be uniquely extended to a continuous linear functional on $W^{1,1}(a,b)$.